# Broken link behaviour in question (doesn't occur in preview)

Tags: support, stack-overflow

See this answer here:
[What Coldfusion 8 standard edition performance monitoring free tools are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589853/what-coldfusion-8-performance-monitoring-free-tools-are-available/1589940#1589940)

The code is as follows:

```
Charlie Arehart's CF411 [lists several monitoring tools][1], some free, some not.

Here's the current list:

* [CFStatShot][3], free, from Dave Spurr. CFStat Yahoo Desktop Widget.
* [ColdFusion AJAX System Monitor][4], free, from Steve Brownlee
...

  [1]: http://www.cf411.com/#cfmon
  [3]: http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/cfstatshot-cfstat-yahoo-desktop-widget/
  [4]: http://www.fusioncube.net/?p=37
```

However, the first link is not being closed, so (in Chrome at least), it's applying all the way to the bulleted list:

```
<div class="post-text"><p>Charlie Arehart's CF411 <a href="http://www.cf411.com/#cfmon" rel="nofollow">lists several monitoring tools, some free, some not.</p> 

<p>Here's the current list:</p> 

<ul>
```

It is always the first link that does it - I added a link in front of that one, and it started misbehaving whilst that one then fixed itself.

I've edited a few times, but the only workaround I've managed to get working is to repeat the first link, like this:

```
Charlie Arehart's CF411 [lists][1] [several monitoring tools][1], some free, some not.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an errant `[` character in your post. I removed it. Fixed.

Comment: Ah, and now you've said that, it immediately jumped out at me as soon as I looked!

Answer (score 0):

Charlie Arehart's CF411 [lists several monitoring tools](http://www.cf411.com/#cfmon), some free, some not.

Here's the current list:

- [CFStatShot](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/cfstatshot-cfstat-yahoo-desktop-widget/), free, from Dave Spurr. CFStat Yahoo Desktop Widget.
- [ColdFusion AJAX System Monitor](http://www.fusioncube.net/?p=37), free, from Steve Brownlee

---

This seems to have worked correctly.

---

Could it be because of the lack of a `[2]:` link?

---

Your original answer was like this

```
Charlie Arehart's CF411 [lists several monitoring tools][2], some free, some not.

Here's the current list:

* [CFStatShot][3], free, from Dave Spurr. CFStat Yahoo Desktop Widget.

  [1]: http://test
  [2]: http://www.cf411.com/#cfmon
  [3]: http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/cfstatshot-cfstat-yahoo-desktop-widget/
```

Note that there was no `[1]:` link, that must have upset the parser.

Comment: Odd. It claims they are the same svn versions, so should have the same behaviour. Perhaps there is something in the rest of the code that breaks it...

Comment: See the full version below - the link runs to the end of the line.
There was a [2]: at one point - it got lost in my various edits, but the problem existed before then, and I've removed links before without it causing problems.

Comment: "Your original answer was like this" - Nope, that's not the original original, that's just the last edit that occurred inside the grace period.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in my first one I manually added the first link as [14] (with CFStatShot link being [1]) and then, assuming that was the problem, I re-numbered to match the order.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: oh! I see.

Comment: when doing manual entry of links, I find it easier to manage using the `[link](http://example.com "title text for link")` idiom for markdown links.

Comment: Ah! I thought there was a different syntax - that would have saved me some time. Although looking at the Formatting Reference (only shown for new questions, not for new comments), the original code used `<a href="...">` which should have worked. :/

Answer (score 0):

Charlie Arehart's CF411 [lists several monitoring tools](http://www.cf411.com/#cfmon), some free, some not.

Here's the current list:

- [CFStatShot](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/cfstatshot-cfstat-yahoo-desktop-widget/), free, from Dave Spurr. CFStat Yahoo Desktop Widget.
- [ColdFusion AJAX System Monitor](http://www.fusioncube.net/?p=37), free, from Steve Brownlee
- ColdFusion JVM Memory Monitor, from Dan Switzer
- [ColdFusion Tracker](http://cftracker.riaforge.org), free, from David Boyer. Access application, session and memory information
- [FlexMon](http://www.cflex.net/flexmon/) CF monitor, free, from Tariq Ahmed (also available at [RiaForge](http://flexmon.riaforge.org/))
- [FusionAnalytics](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/labs/analytics.cfm), commercial, from Intergral (makers of Fusionreactor)
- [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com), commercial, from Intergral
- [Scope Enhancer](http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/scope-enhancer), free tool from Steve Brownlee. Places java system info into the CF Server scope to assist with monitoring JVM setup.
- [SeeFusion](http://www.seefusion.com), commercial, from Webapper
- [ServerStats](http://www.lynchconsulting.com.au/blog/index.cfm/2006/11/9/Hacking-CFMX--pulling-it-all-together-serverStats), free from Mark Lynch
- [WhosOn CFC](http://whosoncfc.riaforge.org/), open source, from Shane Zehnder. Simple tool to help track users visiting your site.

Comment: I've made a few attempts, to correct it. The simple way was the ugly hack that you can see on the revision list (the rest of the edits are hidden because it's within the 5 minutes window).